# How to alternate the case of a string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm working on alternating the case of a string (for example `asdfghjkl` to `AsDfGhJkL`).
I tried to do this. I found some code that is supposed to do it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var str="";

var txt=document.getElementById('input').value;

for (var i=0; i<txt.length; i+2){
    str = str.concat(String.fromCharCode(txt.charCodeAt(i).toUpperCase()));
}
```

Comment: For what type of language the code should work?

Comment: Its for javascript we have to make a virtual keyboard that has alternate function on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick function to do it. It makes the entire string lowercase and then iterates through the string with a step of 2 to make every other character uppercase.

```
var alternateCase = function (s) {
  var chars = s.toLowerCase().split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i += 2) {
    chars[i] = chars[i].toUpperCase();
  }
  return chars.join("");
};

var txt = "hello world";
console.log(alternateCase(txt));
```

> HeLlO WoRlD

The reason it converts the string to an array is to make the individual characters easier to manipulate (i.e. no need for `String.prototype.concat()`).

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work please help me with this.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific if you want help. What did you try? What did not work? Was there an error message or did fail silently? This code runs perfectly fine on my computer, so you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I used the code you give but it didn't change i just only change the value of the txt variable to document.getElementById('input').value to to get the string i want to change

Comment: I have added it to onmousedown event of the button so if i click that button it will change

Comment: What's an example value of `document.getElementById('input').value`? Keep in mind that this code prints the output to the console. If you want to store the result in the `str` variable, do `var str = alternateCase(txt);` instead of `console.log(alternateCase(txt));`.

Comment: document.getElementById('input').value holds the string/ character that i input on my virtual keyboard its a textarea

Comment: Thank you pzp i got it now i just forget to return the change value back to the value of the textarea..

Comment: I made a slightly modified version of this code available as [a Node.js module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alternating-case).

Answer (score 5):

Here an ES6 approach:

```
function swapCase(text) {
    return text.split('').map((c,i) => 
        i % 2 == 0 ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase()
    ).join('');   
}

console.log(swapCase("test"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate the string and alternate between upper-casing the character and lower-casing it:

```
for (var i=0; i<txt.length; i++) {
    var ch = String.fromCharCode(txt.charCodeAt(i);
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        ch = ch.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        ch = ch.toLowerCase();
    }
    str =  str.concat(ch);
}
```

Comment: So it would be just i++ instead of i+2?

Comment: Yup, was definitely supposed to be `i++`. I started by copying the OP's current code and amending it, and neglected to fix the `for` loop itself.