# Alternate capitalisation in a string

Tags: javascript, string, function, for-loop

I would like to create a function which alternates letter capitalisation. For example, `Hello World` would become `HeLlO wOrLd`. The first letter of the string must always be capitalised.

Here is the code I have written:

```
function alternatingCaps(str) {
    let alternate = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    for(let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        let previousChar = str.charAt(i - 1);
        if(previousChar === previousChar.toUpperCase())
            alternate += str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
        else if(previousChar === previousChar.toLowerCase())
            alternate += str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
    }
    return alternate;
}
```

I declared the `alternate` variable with the capitalised first character of the supplied string. I then loop through the rest of the string and check if the character preceding the current iteration is uppercase or lowercase; whichever it is, the current letter will become the opposite.

However, this does not have the desired outcome. Here are a couple of tests and their corresponding results:

```
console.log(alternatingCaps('hello world'));
// Output: "HELLO wORLD"

console.log(alternatingCaps('jAvaScrIPT ruLEZ'));
// Output: "JAvAScRIpt rULez"
```

How do I fix my function?

Comment: What's the desired output of `alternatingCaps('jAvaScrIPT ruLEZ')`?

Comment: Why not just go through the string, alternating between upper and lower case for each non-space character?

Comment: "@AnuragSrivastava JaVaScRiPt RuLeZ

Comment: @HereticMonkey That is what I'm trying to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to alternate the case of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973048/how-to-alternate-the-case-of-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let s = 'hello there this is a test';
s = s.split('').map( (letter,i) => (i % 2) == 0 ?  letter.toUpperCase() : letter.toLowerCase() ).join('')
console.log( s );
```

Update: if you want to ignore but preserve the spaces, then here is another solution, albeit a little screwy.  It doesn't just ignore spaces, it only *operates* on letters matching the regular expression.

```js
let s = 'hello there this is a test';
let ul = false;
s = s.split('').map(letter => letter.match(/[a-zA-Z]/) != null ? (ul = ! ul, ul ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter.toLowerCase()) : letter).join('');
console.log( s );
```

Comment: The "T" in "there" should be lower case. See the OP's example, where the "w" of "world" is lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution i can think of is using [**for**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loop and [**Remainder**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator.

```js
let alterNate = (input) => {
  let str = ''
  let last = 'L'
  for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++){
   if( /[a-z]/ig.test(input[i]) ) {
      if(last==='L'){
        str+= input[i].toUpperCase()
        last = 'U'
      } else{
        str+= input[i].toLowerCase()
        last = 'L'
      }
   } else {
    str+=input[i]
   }
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(alterNate('hello world'))
```

Comment: You need to skip the spaces.

Comment: @adiga added a more robust one. which just alternates all the alphabets ignoring the special characters

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses [RegEx replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to achieve the expected result:

```js
function alternatingCaps(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w(.|$)/g, s => s[0].toUpperCase() + (s[1] ? s[1].toLowerCase() : ''));
}

console.log(alternatingCaps('hello world'));

console.log(alternatingCaps('jAvaScrIPT ruLEZ'));
```

There are two things to pay attention for:

- `\w(.|$)` - This regular expression captures a word character (`\w`) and any other following char. The `(.|$)` address for an odd number of characters. We're basically capturing the characters in pairs here;
- `s => s[0].toUpperCase() + (s[1] ? s[1].toLowerCase() : '')` - This replacing function does the rest of the job:

  - `s[0].toUpperCase()` - It takes `s[0]` and changes it to uppercase;
  - `(s[1] ? s[1].toLowerCase() : '')` - And it takes `s[1]`, if it exists, and changes it to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample regex for alternating case

```
[A-Z]([a-z][A-Z])*[a-z]?
```

https://regex101.com/r/UPHRUk/1