# Add space to string when it includes word in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I have a function where I am iterating through a given string, alternating the capitalisation of each character and concatenating it to variable `alt`.

In order to loop through this properly, I have removed spaces from the original string. But I need to add them back at the end of the function.

```
function alternatingCaps(str) { // 'hello world'
  let words = str.toLowerCase().split(' '); // ['hello','world']
  str       = words.join(''); // 'helloworld'
  let alt = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 === 0)
      alt += str[i].toUpperCase();
    else
      alt += str[i].toLowerCase();
  }
  return alt;
} 

console.log(alternatingCaps('hello world'));
/* Output: "HeLlOwOrLd"
   Wanted output: "HeLlO wOrLd" */
```

Once `alt` contains a string included as a value in the `words` array, I want to add a space at the end of the word.

Here was my attempt:

```
 words.forEach(function(word) {
  if(alt.toLowerCase().includes(word) && word[word.length - 1] === alt[i].toLowerCase())
    alt += ' ';
});
```

It checks if any of the words in the `words` array are present in the `alt` string and if the current character iteration of the string corresponds to the last letter in the word. If so, it adds a space to the string.

But this does not work as intended.

```
> Output: "HeLlO wOr Ld"
> Wanted output: "HeLlO wOrLd"
```

I also imagine this would cause problems with duplicate letters. How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: this was answered.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54988488/3055263

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't join your words. Keep them as separate elements in the words array then you can loop through that array applying you function to each element.

```
function alternatingCaps(str) { // 'hello world'
  let words = str.toLowerCase().split(' '); // ['hello','world']

  const alts = words.map(word => capitalizeEvens(word));
  return alts.join(' ');

  function capitalizeEvens(word) {
    let alt = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if(i % 2 === 0)
        alt += word[i].toUpperCase();
      else
        alt += word[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    return alt;
  } 

console.log(alternatingCaps('hello world'));
```

Comment: Not sure this would work considering `capitalizeEvens` contains a reference to `str` and not `word`...

Comment: I didn't do this because it causes the alternation to refresh with each word; I want it to be continuous. For example, this code would output `HeLlO WoRlD` rather than `HeLlO wOrLd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your string one char at a time. Then, check whether the characters is an actual word character. If so, alternate the capitalization, if not, add it to the output as it is:

```
function altCaps(input) {
  var result = '';
  var cap = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var c = input[i];
    result += /\w/.test(c) ? (cap = !cap) ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase() : c;
  }
  return result;
}
```

**UPDATE:** The legible code

```
function altCaps(input) {
  var result = '';
  var cap = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var c = input[i];
    if (/\w/.test(c)) {               // check if char is a "word character" (i.e. letter)
      cap = !cap;                     // toggle next capitalization
      if (cap)                        // if it should capitalize
        result += c.toUpperCase();    // add uppercase letter
      else
        result +=  : c.toLowerCase(); // add lowercase letter
    } else {
      result += c;                    // no letter, so add character as is.
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I am new to Javascript and am having difficulty following the line with multiple ternary operators. Can you explain how that works?

Comment: Sure, see my update. Basically, you must think of the ternary operator as a simple inline "if-then-else" construct. The more difficult to understand part was the assignment as part of the condition. In Javascript, even an assignment yields a return value, that evaluates to the assigned value. It can therefore immediately be used inside a condition.